# Проектирование структуры базы данных

Tags: sql, база-данных, проектирование

Есть у нас таблица пользователей, есть таблица определенных действий для пользователя. Сводная таблица пользователь-действие-дата на  каждый день для нескольких тысяч пользователей. Как будет производительнее работать БД - общая таблица действий  и выборка `SELECT * FROM routines WHERE id=user` или к каждому пользователю добавлять свою таблицу  и выборка `SELECT * FROM USER_ROUTINES`?  Выборок из сводной таблицы  без `WHERE id=user` (логика задачи) невозможно.
Обобщенный вопрос - что быстрее будет работать:  выборка из большой таблицы с `where` или иметь для каждого пользователя свою  таблицу действий с меньшим количеством записей?

Comment: Вы кстати не указали какая СУБД у вас. В MySQL например одна таблица - 2+ отдельных файлов на диске. В одном каталоге. Чтение каталога (что бы тупо открыть таблицу) очень медленная процедура, если файлов больше 2000. Плюс есть серьезные ограничения на кол-во открытых файлов. И не дай бог  когда через год работы системы вы решите собрать для себя или еще кого, какую нибудь статистику по пользователям, да хоть просто найти пользователей которые давно не пользовались, что бы лишние данные почистить и вам придется городить что то дикое по перебору таблиц. Только одна таблица - без вариантов.

Comment: Или Mysql или PostgreSql

Comment: В общем в любом случае при грамотно построенных индексах скорость работы от количества записей в таблице практически не зависит. Главное что бы запросы не начали полным перебором таблицы идти.

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю, что если имеются индексы, то выборка из общей таблице не должна просаживать производительность. Иметь таблицу под каждого юзера более накладно в сопровождении, на мой взгляд.

Описанная вами система ролей популярна(правда, забыл название).

Есть 3 таблицы:

Action - где описаны допустимые действия.

User- таблица пользователей

UserAction описание того, что каждый юзер может делать.

Comment: Тут скорее задания которые каждый день будут задаваться человеку. Action мне больше кажется все же к политикам. Но не суть важно на самом деле. Иметь огромную таблицу более 100к или 1м  записей не столь накладно,  чем  иметь много персональных  таблиц на каждого пользователя?  по логике работы выборка из таблицы будет идти только только по конкретному пользователю

Comment: @АртемТихонович, Представь, у тебя миллион пользователей и получится, что будет миллион таблиц? Это все сопровождать будет очень накладно. Представь так же, что была какая-то общая роль у каждого пользователя и теперь ее нужно удалить. Получится, что ее придется удалять не из 1 общей таблица, а из Миллиона таблиц. Выборка из персональной таблице скорее всего будет производительной, но будет проблематично все сопровождать и синхронизировать... Так же это протеворечит нормализации, так как по сути между таблицами будут повторяющиеся данные.

Comment: Задача такая, что пользователи абсолютно независимые и ничего общего между ними нет, я на этом акцентирую внимание.  Невозможны операция над группой пользователей или выборки по критерию несколько пользователей. Если из миллиона таблиц то да, конечно это неправильно. Наиболее близкий пример Гугл Календарь но с хранением данных  пользователей в общей бд. Мне например  в 5 утра спортзал. У Ивана в 10 встреча, у Пети в 8 ужин